# "He could do X for England". Are there similar expressions in other parts of the English-speaking world to this derogatory sentence?

Tags: phrases, american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english, australian-english

In Reginald Hill's Dalziel and Pascoe novels, I've read the phrase: "He could [do x] for England. It is always derogatory.  It is a lovely phrase!

Because I can't put my finger on a quote from these books, I'll make up some examples which capture the tone.  A man might say of his wife: "She could shop for England."  Or it might be said of a man with bad table manners: "Don't invite him -- he could belch for England."  A person who has a bad tennis serve might be described as: "She could double-fault for England."

My question is in two parts:  (a) Is this expression widespread in England, or is it confined to the region of the D/P novels (Yorkshire)? (b) Are there similar expressions in other parts of the English-speaking world?

Comment: It may be slightly out of fashion now, but it has been widely used and is certainly understood throughout England.

Comment: And in my experience, it can also be used as a droll compliment: 'She could iron for England.' From [The Greenparent](http://thegreenparent.co.uk/forums/viewthread/2848/P15/#32399) : '... nothing ever gets ironed unless my Mum visits[ –] that woman could Iron for England I'm sure.'

Comment: I'd agree with Edwin. I don't find it to be always derogatory,

Comment: In the US, I've heard *He could win an Olympic medal for belching* and *She's the queen of double-faulting.*

Comment: I've certainly heard it—and Victoria isn't a colony any more.

Answer (score 2):

The literal meaning of this phrase is "he could be on the national or Olympic X team." It's not really derogatory. If X was rowing, or running, for example, it would be a compliment. The reason it often sounds like an insult is that there isn't a national belching, shopping, or double-faulting team so doing that a lot, strongly, or the like is not a good thing.

I have only heard "for England" - no other country seems to have picked it up. You could say "he belongs on the national belching team" or "he is an Olympic belcher" I suppose.